# RecyclerView item replication using adapter

Tags: android, arraylist, android-recyclerview, android-adapter

I have a custom ArrayList containing about 80 to 90 data in it.And I am using RecyclerView to replicate the view in Activity. However, the textview in that view changes as scrolling down or up. Moreover, all the data in my arraylist wont even show up in the adapter.However, I have sorted the list and the list contains all the data in ascending order.Somtime the same data repeats over and over. But if the data are few in the arraylist , then it displays all the items correctly.Did i miss something here.

Here is the code for the adapter and the main activity and my xml and my custom arraylist.

Adapter:

```
public class Adapter_Usage extends RecyclerView.Adapter<Adapter_Usage.View>{
Context context;
CustomTextView txtsessiontime,txtvolupload,txtvoldownload,txtusageyear,txtusageday,txtusagemon;
ArrayList<Info_Usage> listusage;


public Adapter_Usage(Context context, int resource, ArrayList<Info_Usage> listusage) {
    this.context = context;
    this.listusage=listusage;
}
@Override
public View onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
    android.view.View view = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.adapter_usage, parent, false);
    return new View(view);
}


@RequiresApi(api = Build.VERSION_CODES.JELLY_BEAN)
@Override
public void onBindViewHolder(View holder, int position)
{

    Info_Usage infousage = listusage.get(holder.getAdapterPosition());
    String[] arraybilldate = infousage.strdate.split("\\s+");
    txtusageyear.setText(arraybilldate[2]);
    txtusageday.setText(arraybilldate[1]);
    txtusagemon.setText(arraybilldate[0]+", ");
    txtsessiontime.setText(infousage.strsessiontime);
    txtvolupload.setText("Upload : "+infousage.struploads+" MB");
    txtvoldownload.setText("Download : "+infousage.strdownloads+" MB");
}
@Override
public int getItemCount() {
    return listusage.size();
}
public class View extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {

    public View(android.view.View view) {
        super(view);
        txtusageyear=view.findViewById(R.id.txtusageyear);
        txtusageday=view.findViewById(R.id.txtusageday);
        txtusagemon=view.findViewById(R.id.txtusagemon);
        txtsessiontime=view.findViewById(R.id.txtsessiontime);
        txtvolupload=view.findViewById(R.id.txtvolupload);
        txtvoldownload=view.findViewById(R.id.txtvoldownload);
    }
}
}
```

Custom Arraylist:

```
public class Info_Usage {
public String strdate,strdownloads,struploads,strsessiontime,strcurr;

public String getDate() {
    return strdate;
}
public String getcurr() {
    return strcurr;
}
}
```

My activity:

```
Collections.sort(listusage, new Comparator<Info_Usage>()
                    {
                        @Override
                        public int compare(Info_Usage lhs, Info_Usage rhs)
                        {
                            int right=Integer.parseInt(rhs.getcurr());
                            int left=Integer.parseInt(lhs.getcurr());
                            return right<left?1:right>left?-1:0;
                        }
                    });

 if(listusage.size()==0)
            {
                recycler.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                txtnousage.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            }
            else
            {

                txtnousage.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                recycler.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                recycler.setAdapter(new Adapter_Usage(Activity_Usage.this, 0, listusage));
            }
```

Answer (score 0):

You have several issues within your `Adapter`.

1. Return list row view properly within `onCreateViewHolder`:

   ```
   @Override
   public View onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
       return LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.adapter_usage, parent, false);
   }
   ```
2. Access properly to your list' data within `onBindViewHolder`:

   ```
   @Override
   public void onBindViewHolder(View holder, int position) {
       Info_Usage infousage = listusage.get(position);
       String[] arraybilldate = infousage.strdate.split("\\s+");
       txtusageyear.setText(arraybilldate[2]);
       txtusageday.setText(arraybilldate[1]);
       txtusagemon.setText(arraybilldate[0]+", ");
       txtsessiontime.setText(infousage.strsessiontime);
       txtvolupload.setText("Upload : "+infousage.struploads+" MB");
       txtvoldownload.setText("Download : "+infousage.strdownloads+" MB");
   }
   ```

Comment: Sir, the second solution is what I already tried. And the first one I can't use it as it is a custom adapter.